# Get value change update on Binding in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have a binding on my SwiftUI view

```
@Binding var pinValue: String
```

I want to get update every time the value is changed. I tried below as I'd do on a `publisher` but I'm getting errors because it's not a `publisher`.

```
.onReceive($pinValue, perform: { output in
            print(output)
        })
```

I've also tried to access `$pinValue.publisher` but the `.onReceive` block wont' work.

How can I get an update every time the value of `pinValue` is changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
.onChange(of: pinValue) { output in
  print(output)
}
```